# Как отловить ошибку?

Tags: python

Программа падает с ошибкой если открыт результирующий файл

```
>    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/ProjectSED/main.py", line 580, in comparison
    wb.save(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\ProjectSED\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 407, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\ProjectSED\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 291, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\zipfile.py", line 1251, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Результат.xlsx'
```

надо сообщить пользователю что бы он закрыл файл перед работой, думаю сделать это виде исключения,
но не получается её отловить

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(self.filename, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[1, 2, 3, 14, 21]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5],axis=0)
df2 = pd.read_excel(self.filename1, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[2, 3, 4, 5, 20]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],axis=0)
df3 = pd.read_excel(self.filename2, header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 5, 9, 12]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],axis=0)                     

result = df1.loc[df1.ne(df2.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
result2 = df2.loc[df2.ne(df1.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
result3 = df1.loc[df1.ne(df3.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
result4 = df3.loc[df3.ne(df1.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]


datafr = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [result, result3]], axis=0)
datafr1 = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [datafr, result2, result4]], axis=1)

try:
datafr1.to_excel(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Лист', startrow=2,
            startcol=0, header=None, index=False)

except ValueError as ve:
             print(ve)
```

но безрезультатно, что может быть не так?

Comment: Покажите всё-таки более полный стек-трейс, чтобы там и про вашу строчку `datafr1.to_excel` было написано. Возможно, внутри кидается один эксепшен, а выше где-то он ловится и превращается в другой. Ну, мало ли.

Comment: @CrazyElf дополнил вопрос полным выводом ошибки

Comment: ошибка возникает в строчке ``wb.save(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx')``. Соответственно, там надо и исключение ловить. А в приведенном коде этой строчки, и того, что ей предшествует, нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался в моём случае нужно было сделать так

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(self.filename, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[1, 2, 3, 14, 21]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5],axis=0)
df2 = pd.read_excel(self.filename1, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[2, 3, 4, 5, 20]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],axis=0)
df3 = pd.read_excel(self.filename2, header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 5, 9, 12]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],axis=0)                     

result = df1.loc[df1.ne(df2.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
result2 = df2.loc[df2.ne(df1.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
result3 = df1.loc[df1.ne(df3.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
result4 = df3.loc[df3.ne(df1.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]


 datafr = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [result, result3]], axis=0)
 datafr1 = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [datafr, result2, result4]], axis=1)

while True:
try:
  datafr1.to_excel(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', engine='openpyxl',    sheet_name='Лист', startrow=2,
        startcol=0, header=None, index=False)

     break 

except IOError:
  QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message','У вас открыт файл "Результат" закройте файл ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Так и нужно ловить `PermissionError`, а не `ValueError`.

Comment: except PermissionError as ve:

                        print(ve) не работает всё так же.

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ А ловлю всех других видов `Exception` вы убрали? Если да и не ловится, попробуйте просто `Exception`.